# Is there a better way to extract HTML code using Visual Basic

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to extract some HTML code here, I only want the final String to say 
'Entity B'. Is there a better way to do this than what I have done here?
Also this is a format for many entries, so Entity B wont always be Entity B and same for Entity C

```vb
SMethod = "<b>Entity B<br/>Entity C</b>" 
SMethod = SMethod.Replace("</b>", "</c>")
SMethod = SMethod.Replace("<br/>", "</b><c>")
SMethod = "<a>" & SMethod & "</a>"

Dim ShippingMethod As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(SMethod)
SMethod = ShippingMethod.Element("a").Element("b").Value.Trim
```

Comment: Have you considered something like the `HtmlAgilityPack` (available via nuget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what your end game is, but as for the first sentence of your question where you want to take a string with HTML code in it and remove all the code, this function will remove any tag enclosed in `<>`:

```
Public Function RemoveHTML(ByVal input As String) As String
    While InStr(input, "<") > 0
        Dim tagStart As Integer = InStr(input, "<")
        Dim tagEnd As Integer = InStr(input, ">")
        input = Left(input, tagStart - 1) & Right(input, Len(input) - tagEnd)
    End While
    Return input
End Function
```

And if you're also trying to trim off anything after the `<br/>` tag, this will do that:

```
Public Function OneEntity(ByVal input As String) As String
    If InStr(input, "<br/>" Then
        Dim parts() As String = Split(input, "<br/>")
        Return RemoveHTML(parts(0))
    Else
        Return RemoveHTML(input)
    End If
End Function
```